# How to use the $http using vuejs / composition-api?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-composition-api

I'm trying to refactor a few components using composition api. There's a function that needs to send a request.

Since there's no access to `this` on `setup(props, context)` I thought I can use this `context` argument like it was when I was **emitting** an event to parent (`context.emit()`) but it seams to not be the case.

There's an error when using **context**:

```
Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: context.http is undefined""
```

There's an error when using **this**:

```
Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: _this is undefined"
```

Here's a snippet of something I'm trying to achieve:

```
context.http.post('/url'), { data })
  .then(({ data }) => {
    console.log(data)
  });
```

Comment: Try with `context.parent`, this refers to `Vue` or `this`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `vue-resource` as below, `context.parent` is `this` keyword. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-hellman-hdyp5) is the codesandbox link

**main.js**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import VueCompositionApi from "@vue/composition-api";
import VueResource from "vue-resource";

Vue.use(VueCompositionApi);
Vue.use(VueResource);

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

**YourComponent.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app"></div>
</template>

<script>
import { onMounted } from "@vue/composition-api";
export default {
  setup(props, context) {
    onMounted(async () => {
      await context.parent.$http
        .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/")
        .then(response => console.log(response.data));
    });
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I need. I thought I've loged out `context` and its contents.. Thank you!